# How i can initialize sdk from my application class

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, manifest

So I am using a library from GitHub for removing image background. But its giving error when ever I open that class in which I have initialized that library in application class. may be am doing some mistake in android manifest.
here is class where am initializing

```
class RemoveBg : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        RemoveBg.init("aw6M9XaVjMFEn85JRHLfBQg5")



    }
```

it is giving me this error whenever I try to open this

```
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.example.picaeditor, PID: 24421

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.picaeditor/com.example.picaeditor.RemoveBg}:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.picaeditor.RemoveBg cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2881)
```

Kindly help me as am a fesher in android development so experimenting different things. Any kind of help thanks in advance.

Here is my manifest code

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.PicaEditor"
    tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RemoveBg"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".BackgroundRemover"
        android:exported="false" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />

    <activity
        android:name=".AdvanceFeatures"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ResultActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.activity.DsPhotoEditorActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.activity.DsPhotoEditorStickerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.activity.DsPhotoEditorTextActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.activity.DsPhotoEditorCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.activity.DsPhotoEditorDrawActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>
```

Comment: Can you add your manifest code? I think you have accidentally used "RemoveBg" in the `name` field of your main activity instead of your Application. Also, you are going to create big confusion in your code by naming your Application the same thing as that library class you're using.

Comment: got it let me check and thank you so much

Comment: i have also added my manifest code please check and reply thanks in advance

Comment: i have changed class name but still having same error while running it

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up Activities and Application classes and names.

The above class is your Application. You should give it a unique name that ends in "Application" for clarity. For example, you can name it `MyApplication`.

```kotlin
class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        RemoveBg.init("aw6M9XaVjMFEn85JRHLfBQg5")
    }

}
```

Then in your manifest, add a field `android:name=".MyApplication` in the `<application ...>` block. You mistakenly added a new Activity with the name `RemoveBg` by creating new `<activity ... />` blocks. Remove that.

Add the `name` line like this:

```xml
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.PicaEditor"
    tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"
    tools:targetApi="31">
```

Delete this:

```xml
    <activity
        android:name=".RemoveBg"
        android:exported="false" />
```

It's also really weird that you have an Activity named "MainActivity" and another one named "MainActivity2". Make sure you give your classes descriptive names so you can easily understand your own code when you come back to read it in the future. I recommend that you name every activity class with "Activity" at the end of the name of the Activity. This will help make your code a lot easier to understand, especially if you set it aside and then come back to work on it a few days or weeks later.

Comment: Process: com.example.picaeditor, PID: 17893
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                                     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick

Comment: i have added the same line of code in my  manifest as you told me but after that now am getting a new type of error

Comment: That’s not at all related to anything you have described so far.  You should open a new question if you can’t figure that one out from the stack trace, assuming you can’t find it on here already.